Authentication cookies disappears immediately
I'm creating an ASP.NET Core 8 web app without mvc, which is hosted on a local server (not localhost) on a closed network.
The first authentication system was Windows-based but I had to move to authenticate users based on a preexisting database. I implemented cookie based authentication.
It works very well in debug mode on my computer, but when I deploy the website and login, the cookie appears then immediately disappears (I can see it in the cookie window in web inspector briefly) and I get sent back to login.
What could cause this ? Is there a way to know what causes this ?
this server cannot be HTTPS so I had to configure HTTP only cookies. The ASP.NET Core antiforgery cookie stays there.
Here's my cookie configuration in program.cs:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddCookie(options =>
           {
               options.Cookie.Name = "CompetenCielAuth";
               options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
               options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
               options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
               options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
               options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
               options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
               options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
           });

Thanks in advance !


When I deploy the website and login, the cookie appears then
immediately disappears

Based on your scenario and descriptions it seems cookie appears and then disappearing immediately might have several potential issues.
According to your cookie configuration I think one of the reason is, setting options.Cookie.SecurePolicy to CookieSecurePolicy.Always. Becuase as you said, your site is not using HTTPS, the cookie will not be saved. In that case you should Change it to None or SameAsRequest if you're using HTTP.
Secondly, you have used SameSiteMode.Strict for options.Cookie.SameSite property. But Strict can cause issues in some scenarios, particularly with cross-site requests. Therefore, as per your scenario try to use Lax or None
Additionally, you could check your domain and path settings are correctly configured and also check if there any middleware pipelines are not causing anything in between.

What could cause this ? Is there a way to know what causes this ?

In order to investigate what causing the issue has no direct way to know that or no straightforward method to find it out. We mostly need to check application logging, IIS log or event viewer log.
Make sure, you have enabled detailed logging in your application to capture authentication and cookie-related events. You could also inspect the developer tools in your browser to check the cookie and network requests. Check for any errors or warnings related to cookies.
Note: Please refer to this official document if you need further assistance.
